# Famous franchises in D&D

Tags: dnd-5e

Does anyone know if there are any adaptations of famous stories like the Wizard of Oz, Alice in Wonderland, Red Riding Hood and others like those, for D&D 5e?

Comment: If you have a specific story in mind, I'm sure answers could look for a D&D adaptation of that story. But a list of any and all adaptations of every famous story ever is way too broad.

Comment: Also, are you asking about WotC material? 3rd-party published stuff? Homebrew?

Comment: WotC is always preferred but any will help! I'm just looking for stories that are already familiar to people, to put in my campaign.

Comment: Ok, that's way too broad for here; you might want to try a [forum](http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/q/5449/15469).